# Programatically Check if the items if the item's version that is returned is a Fall Back

Tags: language-fallback

I have a scenario where I have to enable the fallback for a template and on some particular scenarios I have to show the language versions only if it has that particular version. 
Ex: If it has a non english version show that version only in that language(no fall back)
Item.Versions.count>0  returns true if I set Enable fall back to true.
Is there a way I check if the version that is returned is fall back version speifically

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can call `Item.IsFallback`, which returns true if the item in question is fallback item.

Source:

https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up_and_maintaining/language_fallback/setting_up/language_fallback__changes_to_apis

Answer (score 2):

You can use property `IsFallBack`. As per sitecore's [documentation](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/81/setting_up_and_maintaining/language_fallback/setting_up/language_fallback__changes_to_apis)

> The Sitecore.Data.Item class
>
> The following properties have been added to the class:
>
> OriginalLanguage – a property that returns the original language for the current item. If the item is not a fallback item, it returns the item.Language.
>
> IsFallback – a property that returns true if the current item is a fallback item.

Answer (score 0):

The Item class (in Sitecore.Kernel.dll, SC 8.1+) has a IsFallback property that will indicate if the item is a fallback item.

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets a value that indicates if the item is a fallback item.
/// </summary>
/// <value>
/// <c>true</c> if this item is a fallback item; otherwise, <c>false</c>.
/// </value>
public bool IsFallback
{
    get
    {
    return this._originalLanguage != (Language) null;
    }
}
```